# Laptop mysteriously goes blank

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, dell-studio

My Laptop screen turns off randomly

The facts :

- Dell Studio 15 Laptop display randomly and mysteriously goes blank .
- Randomly comes back if I try turning it on and off about 10 times or maybe give the laptop a little shake.
- Last time this happened I took it for a repair and at that point it randomly came back to life . The guys there checked it out anyway and said it was fine .
- It was fine for a week but now its back .  If you guys have any clues on the possiblities maybe I can get that component replaced or give the repair guy some clues on where to look .

I suspect there is some loose contact or something in the powersystem or the display .

Comment: What does 'goes blank' mean? The laptop is off? Just the screen is off? It forgets something? A textbox on screen is blank?

Comment: The screen goes off . But its still powered on . Like the backlight is on but the display is still blank . When I turn it off and then back on even the backlight will be off .

Comment: When it turns off, how do you fix the issue? A reboot, wait some time, shake the device?

Comment: Is there any image recovered if you move the screen either further, to open, or in the closing direction while it is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue on my laptop too (in my case it is an Acer and not a Dell, but it seems that the symptoms are the same). I don't know if this applies to you, but I'll explain how I managed it.

In my case, it was a kinda loose cable inside the laptop, and in particular (of course!), the one that bring the signal to the monitor.

The first, temporary solution was to turn the screen-lid a bit back and forth, until the monitor was working again, but in the long run, I ended in breaking one of the hinges.
So take care, it is a fast solution and usually works, but continuous movement on the hinges could cause damage.

I managed to solve it in a more permanent way by opening the laptop and manually trying to better plug the cable in its position. But this kind of DIY work require you to know what you are doing; it is not so difficult (I'm not a technician after all, and I did it) but must be done with caution.
This could be different from laptop to laptop, but I only had to remove the middle cover (located between the keyboard and the monitor), and better fix the cable in there.
If you are looking to fix it that way, I suggest you to look for a guide on [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/) or [FixYa](http://www.fixya.com/), or even better, search on the [Dell website](http://www.dell.com/support/Manuals) for a service or disassembly manual.